# Not able to resolve 'tty' in node module

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am getting this error in ReactJs + styled components. How can I fix it?

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/colorette/index.js 1:0-27

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tty' in 'C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Documents\react projects\disney-plus-clone\node_modules\colorette'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "tty": require.resolve("tty-browserify") }'
    - install 'tty-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "tty": false }
```

At first I was declaring my styled components as follows:

```js
const DropDown = styled.div`
position: relative;
top: 10vh;
left: 100vw;
border: 2px solid yellow`
${ div }:
    border: 2px solid white;
```

I got a compilation error as expected because `${}` syntax had to be inside the backticks.

But after removing that suddenly I got the "tty" error.

Comment: The syntax error you were initially getting is not really relevant to the question. Webpack starts by parsing your code, and if it can't do that due to invalid syntax, it exits with an error (without trying to do any bundling). Once the syntax error is fixed, it proceeds with attempting to bundle, and shows you any bundling-related errors, such as the tty error in your question.

Answer (score 4):

`tty` is a Node.js-only module used to manage text terminals (i.e. your command line). It should not be used in browser-facing code, like React apps.

Your file seems to be importing `colorette`, which is designed for command line interfaces, not React apps.

Verify that your file does not import `colorette`. If you have third-party dependencies, check that they do not use `colorette` as well. If they do, you'll need to remove it.

The recommendation to install `tty-browserify` should be ignored. Unless you are developing for the command line, `tty` should not appear in browser code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to import a third-party module, `colorette`, which is built for node and does not have browser support. You can tell this because `tty` is a global module available only in a node environment. This also makes sense because `colorette` is for colouring terminal text, so it has no place in your browser code.

You may have accidentally imported server code into your client. Sometimes this can happen accidentally if you import some index file somewhere that requires both server and client things. That won't work, even if the client only uses client stuff from that index, since Webpack can't statically analyse the imports of everything in that index.

You need to methodically ensure you have not imported server code anywhere in your browser application.